# How to draw animated UIImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

Trying to draw animated UIImage like so:

```
// Image
    UIImage *image = [UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"progress_" duration:0.5f];
    CGPoint imagePoint = CGPointMake(self.center.x - roundf(image.size.width / 2.0f), self.center.y - roundf(image.size.height / 2.0f) - boxHeight / 8.0f);
    [image drawAtPoint:imagePoint];
```

That doesn't work, I see only first frame.
I tried same code but assigning this image to UIImageView and it works.

So, how do I make this image working? Or how do I draw UIImageView inside rect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really shouldn't draw `UIImage` or `UIImageView` on your own, why? What you need is to add your `UIImageView` as a subview and let it draw itself, that's how things work generally.

Comment: Basically, you override `-drawRect:` when there is some actual custom drawing to do, like fancy indicators, shapes and so on. This usually involves grabbing a graphics context and doing some actions with QuartzCore. MBProgressHUD is a good example, as they don't use any images for their graphics. However, it is really easier to rely on view hierarchy when dealing with such things as displaying images - you can benefit from powers of Core Animation and Auto Layout.